# Android runOnUiThread() in a synchronous call

Tags: android, multithreading

To run something in Main thread from other thread we call `runOnUiThread()`. Question is, this call is synchronous or asynchronous?

If I want to run something synchronously in main thread, how do I do that?

Comment: Note: if you often call `runOnUiThread()` (like few milliseconds apart) from your background thread that will just   slowdown your MainThread which also defeat the purpose of using a background thread.

Comment: @Enzokie I dont want to do like that. I have to call synchronous call from other thread to main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "run something asynchronously in the main thread" because that's not how asynchronous logic works. For something to be asynchronous it *has* to run on a different thread, otherwise it wouldn't, by definition, be asynchronous.

`runOnUiThread()` posts the Runnable you pass to the main thread's Handler. It then runs on the main thread at the next available opportunity.

Don't put any heavy logic on the main thread. `runOnUiThread()` is used so you can update UI elements, like TextViews or ProgressBars, when something happens in the asynchronous logic.

Answer (score 1):

It's asynchronous. It returns immediately without waiting for the task you post finished running.

To run something synchronously in main thread:

If your are in the main thread, just run it.

If your are in a different thread. You need some synchronization mechanism. For example, you can use a semaphore. Acquire a semaphore in the background thread, and let the runnable you passed in runOnUiThread to release that semaphore after it finished running. This way your background thread will wait for the runnable. Well, it's still asynchronous in the eyes of the main thread. But it is synchronous in the eyes of the background thread.

Comment: so you are saying there is no way from framework to handle it without implementing semaphore manually?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan If you need to wait for another thread you have to use some synchronization mechanism. Or if your background thread has a looper. You can post the remaining task as a new runnable back to the background thread after the runnable in the main thread finished running. This is all asynchronous but the execution is serial.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan  If you don't care which background thread for the remaining task to run, you don't even need a looper. Just execute the remaining task in a thread pool, like AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.